# Dynamically assign resource for database in Java based web application

Tags: java

I'm playing java based web application recently. Here is a barrier that I couldn't figure it out for long period. Hope someone can give some hints.

In my case, I used two xml files for pre-configuration. One is database resources' details include URLs, usernames, passwords and so on while the another one is simple selection options for DOM later. The purpose I want to use xml files for pre-configuration is to make my program as dynamic as possible. Hence, any updated in one of my database, I can just change the two xml files instead of the source codes.

In order to achieve that, I needed to dynamically assign database resource based user's selection. My personal idea to obtain this goal is through following procedures in Controller or Servlet class:

```
// get user's selected option from request, create Input object       
String userSelection = request.getParameter("title");
Input userInput = new Input(userSelection);     

// open user selection options xml inside Input class
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile); 

// get matched option and set database name inside Input class
if(userSelectoin.equals(doc.getElementByTagName("desiredTitle"))
{
   userInput.setDB(doc.getElementByTagName("dbname");  
}

// use resource injection to get all details of corresponding database in database xml
@Resource(name=userInput.getDB())
public void doConnection()
{
   DataSource myDB;
   Connection myConn = myDB.getConnection(); 
}
```

The barrier lies at the fourth procedure. For resource injection, its name needs constant string such as `@Resource(name="myDB1")`. However the tradeoff is it may make program not dynamic at all. My query will be how to set and get final String in java or is there any other possible solution to get my goal ?

The error message from Eclipse is "The value for annotation attribute Resource.name must be a constant expression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed what zvzdhk mentioned in his suggestion, I have successfully implemented dynamic database selection during runtime. Below codes are my implementation details:

```
Connection conn = null; 
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DatSource)ctx.lookup("java:com/env"+userInput.getDB());

if(ds != null)
{
    conn = ds.getConnection();
}
```

NOTE: Remember to set the databsources pool under WebContent/META-INF/context.xml or tomcat/config/context.xml. At the same time, copy the jdbc drive jar file to tomcat/lib/ folder. If you are using MySQL, it will be mysql-connector-java.jar. While if you are using IBM DB2, it will be db2jcc.jar, db2jcc4.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar.

Hope this answer can help others. Here is the best resource I have found, feel free to take a look. It will benefits not only project but also yourself. [Choose best Database Connectivity with Java web application](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-best-database-connectivity-web/)

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic data sources, you'd be much better off by using jndi resources:

Define a data source in your web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Then in your controller:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/myDS")
private DataSource myDS;

public void doSomething() {
  Connection conn = myDS.getConnection();
  ...
}
```

It is then down to the application server to define the data source in its configuration (usually through a console), completely separating the database config from your app and usually giving you connection pooling for free.

Comment: Dear beny23, thanks for your suggestion. That's exactly what I did now. I have defined data sources in my web.xml under /WebContent/META-INF. However, the problem is I was playing with few databases instead of one. Hence, my program needed to dynamically choose database source during run time based on users' selection.